# How to show a new div with the same input box in the parent div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to display a search text box and popup box aligned on the left top of the windows.

There is already a `search input box` in the navbar. When the user clicks on that `input box`, I want to popup another div exactly of the same width and use the same input box as the part of the new div.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  var searchboxelement = document.getElementById("search_header_card");
  var headerclose = document.getElementById("header_close");

  var inputheaderbox = document.getElementById("header_input_box");
  var headerClose = document.getElementById("header_close");
  inputheaderbox.addEventListener("click", showSearchBox, false);

  headerClose.addEventListener("click", searchclose, false);

  function showSearchBox() {
    searchboxelement.classList.remove("d-none");
  };

  function searchclose() {
    searchboxelement.classList.add("d-none");
  };

});
```

```css
.body-color {background-color:red}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav.navbar {
  align-content: center;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 75);
  padding: 0px 20px;
  /* REMOVED TOP PADDING */
}

.fas .fa-search {
  color: #65676b;
}

.header__left>img {
  height: 40px;
}

.header__left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__input {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eff2f5;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 999px;
}

.header__input>input {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline-width: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.header__center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*modified css */

.header__center__option {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 60px;
}

.header__center__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px #f8f9fa, inset 0 -3px #f8f9fa;
}

.header__center__item.active,
.header__center__item.active:hover {
  color: #1877f2;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #1877f2;
  border-bottom-width: 3px; */
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

.header__center__item:hover {
  background-color: #e9ebef;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.header_option-link {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 52px;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  justify-content: center;
  color: gray;
}

.header__center__item.active>.header_option-link {
  color: #1877f2;
}

.header_option-link:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.header__center__item.active {
  color: #1877f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1877f2;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  right: 2px;
  left: 2px;
}

.search__header__card__input {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
}

.search__header__card {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 60px;
  width: 320px;
}

.search__box {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.header__close {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #e4e6eb;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<body class="body-color">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light py-xl-0 py-md-0 py-sm-0 py-2">
    <div class="header__left">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Free_logo.svg/600px-Free_logo.svg.png" />
      <div class="header__input">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        <input id="header_input_box" placeholder="Search Facebook" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div id="search_header_card" class="search__header__card d-none">
        <div class="search__header__card__input">
          <div id="header_close" class="header__close">
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="header__input">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            <input class="" placeholder="Search Your Desitnation" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="search__box">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo modi quis nobis hic saepe suscipit dolorem sint atque cumque. Fuga enim labore facere velit veritatis. Animi, eum eveniet. Nostrum, ratione.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header__center d-none d-xl-flex d-md-flex d-sm-flex">
      <ul class="header__center__option">
        <li class="header__center__item active">
          <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-plane fa-lg"></i>
          </a>
          <div class="header__option-line"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

As shown in the image, the input box behind the card is popping out and not covered by outside divs.

[image]

What is the best way to use the same input box in a new div? Or, what could be another workaround to cover the input box that is behind, by a new input box which is in the new div with class `search__header__card__input`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not hide the input box on the nav-bar when a user clicks on it and bring it back when the user clicks on the close button of the newly created div element?

To do so,

In your showSearchBox function, you can add

```
 inputheaderbox.style.display = "none";
```

And in your closesearch function, add

```
 inputheaderbox.style.display = "initial";
```

I think this is the best solution cause it just requires 2 lines of code in your js file

[Check out this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jg8Ld10c/1/)

Comment: Hiding is not the issue here! hiding won't give me the solution that I wanted.